# How should i structure the code so Facebook and Google+ fetch the right elements when someone shares an url?

Tags: html, optimization, semantics, markup

I was wondering which elements are fetched when an user shares an url on Facebook or Google+...
For example: how can i make sure the description of the post will be the description i want to be shared and the image will be the image i want to be shared?
Title is pretty obvious, so i skipped that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook suggests the opengraph protocol: http://ogp.me

It works reliable and can be checked with the facebook url linter http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Comment: I'll have to rely on OpenGraph for now and look for something else for Google+. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I just wrote a [blog post](http://remember-this-url.blogspot.com/2011/07/social-network-optimization.html) about this this week. It seems to me that there's no reliable way of knowing how either social network site will parse your web page to get the "status" version of it. Not only does each site do it differently (i.e. FB, vs. linkedin vs. G+), but they're liable to change it at a whim.

So currently the short answer is that you can't know this for sure. You have to reverse engineer each social network site's behavior and hope it doesn't change too often. That is until the industry smartens up and decides on some markup to convey, for example, which image form a page is considered the cardinal "share" image, and so on.

Comment: I love the SNO term, very well coined. :)